# Circle geometry question regarding finding angles

Tags: geometry, circles

> Circle $P$ has diameter $CD$. Point $B$ is on the circle such that $m\angle BPC=30$ degrees. Point $A$ is on the circle such that $AD$ is parallel to $PB$.
>
> What is the degree measure of arc $ABC$?

I am stuck on how to draw this diagram and go about solving the problem. Do realise the answer must be $60$ degrees, but don't understand how. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please type your question in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of using an image.

Comment: What are you stuck on when drawing the diagram?

Comment: @Tumul Kumar Easy to see that $\measuredangle APC=2\cdot30^{\circ}=60^{\circ}.$

Comment: Where should points A, P and B go? Do they go on the diameter or the circumference?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg how did you obtain that?

Comment: @TumulKumar I assumed that $P$ was the centre, and $A$ and $B$ were on the circumference

Comment: Once you draw the diagram, find $\angle ADP$, $\angle PAD$, and $\angle APD$. If you have any more questions please comment below.

Comment: @TobyMak ∠ =30 degrees, but how to obtain ∠ and ∠?

Comment: Notice that $PA$ is also a radius of the circle. $PA = PD$ which means that $\Delta APD$ is what kind of triangle?

Comment: @TobyMak oh yes APD is an isosceles, thus ∠=30 deg, ∠=120 deg. And Δ is congruent to ΔBCP. Should ∠ABC be 150 deg then?

Comment: No, it's $60º$. I'll update my answer to show why.

Comment: thanks @TobyMak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my attempt at the drawing:

[image]

From the information in the comments, we find that $\angle PAD = \angle ADP = 30º$ ($PA=PD$ since they are both radii, so $\Delta PAD$ is isosceles. Therefore $\angle PAD = 120º$ which gives $\angle APC = 60º$.

This can also be found using the [exterior angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem), which in this case, means that $\angle PAD + \angle ADP = \angle APC$.

Just to clarify, 'degree measure' means the angle of rotation from one side to the other side, *not* the angle in between the arc. This is further explained in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ow1Lgu8VV0g) YouTube video.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is my attempt on the drawing.

Comment: Sorry for wrong angle nomenclature, just flip the image in your head ^^

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the angle to be measured should be $\angle APC$.

Comment: Correct, sorry for that.